# How do you hide the scrollbars in the MDI Child form?

Tags: delphi, mdi

How do you hide the scrollbars in the MDI Child form?
when i ran my project, my mdi child form showing scrollbar automatically. And no setting at all to show that scrollbar. it show horz and vert scrollbar.

I'm already setting AutoScroll to false, VertScrollBar to false and HorzScrollbar to false, but does not seem to work. i'm using delphi 11.3

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem, so I must be doing something different from what you do. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You can hide the scrollbars of MDI child forms simply by setting property `AutoScroll := False`. However, since you mention that you already did that, I suspect that you actually mean the scrollbars of the MDI parent form. They are not affected by setting the MDI parent forms `AutoScroll` because the parent form has a separate MDI Client Window whos settings are not directly accessible. The scrollbars you see in the MDI parent form are the scrollbars of this MDI Client window. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3367373/2292722) for further advice.